# Debugging ASP.NET without code-behind file

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering how does any interface with database been done without using code behind e.g. C# or VB in ASP.NET?

Actually I am trying to debug an application which require further update / enhancement, but it seems that the aspx page does not have and .cs or .vb file. In the header, only mention Inherits some kind of function like "user_changepass", but when I using search function in VS (for whole solution), I could not find particular function, to edit/understand better.

In the folder also only contains JS script, CSS files, images, config file etc. Nothing about the query script etc.

Hoping for some ideas to shed the light on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late for the answer but as this post is still open I thought this might help someone else who comes across such issue.
In the above scenario your best option is to use reflector  or any other decompiling tool like dotpeek to decompile the DLLs in order to recreate the source code.
Similar post [How do I debug an asp.net program without code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386273/how-do-i-debug-an-asp-net-program-without-code-behind)