# How do I debug an asp.net program without code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, code-behind

I inherited a web site that I know little about.  I've worked with asp.net/C# websites, but this seems to be something different.  There is no code behind for me to put a break point and step through it.  Also several refernces in the program can't be found.  My general question is: How do I debug this program in Visual Studio?

Specifc questions related to this sample code:

- Where do I put my break point?
- What happens in this sample when a user clicks the submit button?
- The program inherits "Company.Program.SystemLogin".  I can't find that class in any of the code.  Why not and how do I find it?

  ```
   <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Company.Program.SystemLogin" %>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
   <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <title>Company CMS</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1">
    <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript">
    <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
    <style>
    BODY { FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff }
     INPUT { FONT-SIZE: 11px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif }
     TEXTAREA { FONT-SIZE: 11px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif }
     SELECT { FONT-SIZE: 11px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif }
      TD { FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif }
     .red { FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #851205 }
     .orange { FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #e05e02 }
     .message { FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12px; COLOR: #e05e02 }
     </style>
     </HEAD>
     <body onload="document.getElementById('txtUsername').focus();">
     <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">


              <table width="400" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" align="center">
                  <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" align="center"><img src="images/pcms.jpg" alt="Company CMS"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Runat="server" CssClass="message">PLEASE LOGIN</asp:Label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td align="right" class="red">Username</td>
                      <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" Runat="server" />
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rUsername" Runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" Text="*" Font-Bold="True"
                              Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#E05E02" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td align="right" class="red">Password</td>
                      <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" Runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rPassword" Runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" Text="*" Font-Bold="True"
                              Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#E05E02" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td align="right" class="red"><asp:label id="lblconn" Runat="server" Visible="False">Connection:</asp:label></td>
                      <td><asp:DropDownList ID="conns" Runat="server" Visible="False">
                              <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" align="center"><asp:Button id="btnSubmit" Runat="server" Text="Log In" CssClass="button" /></td>
                  </tr>
              </table>

      </form>
  </body>
  ```

Comment: Where do you want to set your breakpoint if you have no execution code?

Comment: Is this a compiled web application? Is there a bin folder with a DLL named Company or Company.Program? In which case you'll need the original project files and then you will be able to debug locally like you're used to.

Comment: I know nothing else about this project.  I want to set a break point because I need to make changes and I don't know where to make them.  For example, when the submit button is clicked, what happens?  Does it compare the value in the text boxes to a database?  etc.

Comment: I don't know if it's a compiled web application.  How would I know?  I certainly don't have any "original project files".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have inherited an application without source code, you have a tough challenge ahead of you.

You could use dotpeek or reflector to decompile the DLLs in order to recreate the source code, but this will be an onerous task.

My first point of call would be to find out if the source code was available anywhere.

Comment: This seems to be correct.  Looks like the code must be in the .dll's.

Comment: @Fenton Since this question is quite old, if possible, could you suggest how to debug an asmx without code behind when I have the source code because I don't see any place to add a breakpoint? Thanks.